# Null value issue while Data Migration?

Tags: java, sql, database, oracle

We have one table with set of columns for ver 1 of application. For ver 2 we added one more column of `CHAR(1)` type accepts only 'Y' or 'N' (boolean in java) with not null constraint. So while data migration ver 1 to ver 2, we have this column filled with null values as this column is not present in ver 1. Since this is not null column and boolean type in java will not accept null value, it will throw exception in java. Please let me know what is best solution to avoid this.

some solutions i thought of :

1. Change boolean to Boolean object. Boolean accepts null value. This resolves the issue but does not seems to be good solution. As we have not null constraint, we should avoid null value being added in table, otherwise it is corrupt record.
2. Put default value in alter scripts of table, so record with no value for column is added it assigns the default value instead of null
3. Migrate data. After that execute modify script for column to change all null value to default value.

Using JAVA 8, Oracle DB

Comment: What version of Oracle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data Migration is one time activity. It will be good if you provide default value at table level which is your second solution; so definitely go with it. This will take care of your one time migration stuff as well it make it future-proof.

Answer (score 0):

your are providing not null constraint on column so third approach is wrong. In first case you need to handle null values in your java code otherwise possible to come null pointer exception. so I will suggest prefer primitive type boolean and provide default value so handling in code becomes easy